# Delete child in a one-to-one relationship with entity framework

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I do have three entities: **Recipe**, **Ingredient** and **Nutrition**.
Either Recipe and Ingredient can have a Nutrition information.

I configured a one-to-one relationship with shared key.
Reason: **I would like to use same table 'Nutrition' for both Ingredient and Recipe entities**.

**Problem**:
If I delete a Recipe-/Ingredient entity the entity framework will not automatically delete the Nutrition entry in database.

Entities - Example

```cs
public class Recipe
{
    public int RecipeId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Instructions { get; set; }

    // Foreign key for the one-to-one relationship
    public int NutritionId { get; set; }

    // Navigation property for referencing shared Nutrition
    public Nutrition Nutrition { get; set; }
}

public class Ingredient
{
    public int IngredientId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    // Foreign key for the one-to-one relationship
    public int NutritionId { get; set; }

    // Navigation property for referencing shared Nutrition
    public Nutrition Nutrition { get; set; }
}

public class Nutrition
{
    // Shared key with Recipe and Ingredient
    [Key]
    public int NutritionId { get; set; }

    public int Calories { get; set; }
    public int Protein { get; set; }
    public int Carbohydrates { get; set; }
    public int Fat { get; set; }

    // Navigation properties for referencing Recipe and Ingredient
    public Recipe Recipe { get; set; }
    public Ingredient Ingredient { get; set; }
}
```

AppDbContext - Example

```cs
public class AppDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Recipe> Recipes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Ingredient> Ingredients { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Nutrition> Nutritions { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        // Configure the database connection
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("YourConnectionStringHere");
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        // Configure one-to-one relationship between Recipe and Nutrition
        modelBuilder.Entity<Recipe>()
            .HasOne(recipe => recipe.Nutrition)
            .WithOne(nutrition => nutrition.Recipe)
            .HasForeignKey<Recipe>(recipe => recipe.NutritionId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

        // Configure one-to-one relationship between Ingredient and Nutrition
        modelBuilder.Entity<Ingredient>()
            .HasOne(ingredient => ingredient.Nutrition)
            .WithOne(nutrition => nutrition.Ingredient)
            .HasForeignKey<Ingredient>(ingredient => ingredient.NutritionId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
    }
}
```

Delete - Example:

```cs
var ingredient = context.Ingredients
                    .Include(i => i.Nutrition)
                    .SingleOrDefault(x => x.IngredientId == id);

context.Ingredients.Remove(ingredient);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use OnDeleteCascade in configure your modelbuiler. Here is the correct code, replace it with your OnModelCreating method:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Recipe>()
        .HasOne(recipe => recipe.Nutrition)
        .WithOne(nutrition => nutrition.Recipe)
        .HasForeignKey<Recipe>(recipe => recipe.NutritionId)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Ingredient>()
        .HasOne(ingredient => ingredient.Nutrition)
        .WithOne(nutrition => nutrition.Ingredient)
        .HasForeignKey<Ingredient>(ingredient => ingredient.NutritionId)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply - Sorry, forgot to mention that I already tried this. And I think this is also the default behavior? Anyways in both cases it's not working.